# Weird behavior of Mongoose FindByIdAndUpdate - why is it deleting a document instead of updating?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the code :

```
await Employees.findByIdAndUpdate(
      empId,
      {
        Absence: newAbsenceCode,
        InsertDate: undefined,
        RegistrationDate: undefined
      },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true
      }
    );
```

I'm only updating one field , `newAbsenceCode` , however from some weird reason `findByIdAndUpdate` deletes the document.

I've tested it multiple times and the document is really deleted , why ?

Comment: Do you mean the Employee document is being deleted?  Can you add all code for Employees schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `omitUndefined:true` option

```
await Employees.findByIdAndUpdate(
  empId,
  {
    Absence: newAbsenceCode,
    InsertDate: undefined,
    RegistrationDate: undefined
  },
  {
    new: true,
    omitUndefined:true,
    runValidators: true
  }
);
```